# How to change dynamically text with Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to change text dynamically. SO when i doubleclick on text it appear in input and i can just clear text and write another.

Here is my starting code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/006853mL/)

```
<div id="main_text">
    <h1>Change Text</h1>
</div>



$('.main_text').dblclick(function(){
    var val = $("#main_text").value();  

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "appear in input"? It is not clear on what do you click and what should be changed.

Comment: You mean like `contentEditable="true"`? Please be clear to what you want

Comment: Yes the contentEditable="true" is that what i need, Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```js
$('#main_text').dblclick(function(){
    var $elm = $(this);
    
 $elm.find("h1").replaceWith($("<input />", {
     val: $elm.text(),
        change: function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            
         $elm.html($("<h1 />", {
             text: text
            }));
        }
    }));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_text">
    <h1>Change Text</h1>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/006853mL/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

Edit: I added a keylistener. If you press enter, it will apply the changes.

```js
$('#main_text').dblclick(function() {
  var currentText = $(this).children('h1').text();
  $(this).children('h1').replaceWith('<input class="change" type="text" value="' + currentText + '"/>');
  $('.change').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var currentText = $('.change').val();
      $(this).replaceWith('<h1>' + currentText + '</h1>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_text">
  <h1>Change Text</h1>
</div>
```